# font-awesome not displaying correctly in wordpress bones theme

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

Trying to get font awesome to work properly in wordpress, i am currently using the bones theme with the visual composer plugin. 
if i make a wysiwyg html box and copy some info in there with the class for font awesome it shows the icon however when published to the site it shows nothing. link below is the backend with icon appearing in preview but not text.
[backend page content](http://prntscr.com/80n9wx)
Frontend not displaying it either
[front end not displaying](http://prntscr.com/80nar3)

I have enqueued it like this:

```
  // Font Awesome Icons
  function font_awesome() {
  // CDN Network For Font Awesome Icons
  wp_register_style('font_awesome','http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('font_awesome');

  add_action('wp_print_styles', 'font_awesome');
}
```

have i missed something or is this a bug? any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Try with this link instead : `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` - The netdna one give me an Access Denied, don't know why - though the maxcdn one seems to work great.

Comment: changed the link but no luck, browser shows its there but im not sure if its stripping it out, i know wordpress is prone to stripping out tags: http://prntscr.com/80nij6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw that your `add_action` call is *inside* your `font_awesome` function. So your function will never be called, and the font awesome script will never be enqueued.

Moreover, you shouldn't use `wp_print_styles` [as it is deprecated since WP 3.3](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/) and can provoke an incompatibility that make the scripts enqueue in admin. Use [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) instead:

```
function font_awesome() {
  wp_register_style('font_awesome','http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('font_awesome');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'font_awesome');
```